# Fixing the "Environment location directory is not empty" error

Tags: pycharm, python-3.10, pythoninterpreter

I was coding for my game and installed the Python 3.10 interpreter. I choose the interpreter amd suddenly my PyCharm 2023.1 said the error `"Environment location directory is not empty"`.
[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofoCq.png)

I tried to change to a second Python interpreter but PyCharm said that the interpreter is invalid and I can't click OK.

Comment: Change the "Location" field. E.g., `E:\Custom\Concepts\PyCharm Projects\SpaceBattle\.venv` This way the virtual environment will be stored inside `.venv` folder in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I tried manually creating virtual environment inside of .venv and then adding the interpreter. Turns out this causes the issue mentioned.

Instead, delete the .venv and then select location as mentioned by @Pavel Karateev, pycharm will create virtual environment for you, no need of manually creating it.